# python feature selection : contradiction between chi2 and chi2_contingency

Tags: python, scipy, feature-selection

Both **scipy.stats.chi2_contingency** and **sklearn.feature_selection.chi2**
can be used to calculate chi2 statistic and pvalues. These can be further used to select the top K relevant features. If we have a dataset with (nrows,nfeatures) of predictors and target values
(nrows) then chi2 can be used to determine which features among nfeatures are most important in terms of the target variable being dependent on them. Assume all variable to be categorical.

The issue is that the test statistic (and pvalues) calculated using **chi2_contingency** and **chi2** are different for the same dataset !  This leads to a different subset of selected features. Which of the two functions should be used for feature selection (and why ?).